# Dynamically create CSV file using select statement in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, csv

I have a website which allows users to download data using specific search criteria (country and dates) to a CSV File. They pick all the information from a dropdown list and a JQuery datepicker.

The export works perfectly for small data sets, but as soon as you try and download 10000 rows of data, it takes a really long time and may even timeout!

I have tried different ways of doing this, but I'd like to stick to this method due to time constraints in this project.

My code is as follows:

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {

            if (country.Contains("GB"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from " + logData + " where country in ('GB') and close_date between '" + fromDate + "' and '" + toDate + "'"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);

                            //Build the CSV file data as a Comma separated string.
                            string csv = string.Empty;

                            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                //Add the Header row for CSV file.
                                csv += column.ColumnName + ',';
                            }
                            //Console.Write(cmd);
                            //Add new line.
                            csv += "\r\n";

                            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                                {
                                    //Add the Data rows.
                                    //Response.Write(row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',');
                                      csv += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                                }

                                //Add new line.
                                csv += "\r\n";
                            }

                            //Download the CSV file.
                             Response.Clear();
                            Response.Buffer = true;
                            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=data.csv");
                            Response.Charset = "";
                            Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                            Response.Output.Write(csv);
                            Response.Flush();
                            Response.End();
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
```

> Response.Write(row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',');
>
> csv += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';

If I use **Response.Write**..., the file download is **MUCH** faster, but the data is all on one row and doesn't include headers. 
**CSV += row... is much slower and occasionally times out**

How do I separate the data onto multiple rows if I was to use Response.Write and include headers?

The actual SQL query takes 2 seconds to run and produces 12231 records

Comment: use string builder like this ... > StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();...
SB.Append(row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";")); SB.Append(','); ...string builder  is much faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to hold the whole resultset (from your `SELECT`) in RAM, twice. Don't forget that the point of SQL is, basically, to let you work with data sets that are bigger than any RAM you have.  It doesn't mean you have to do that, but it does mean you should think "a row at a time" when designing your software.

Anyway, you're loading your whole result set into RAM, twice.

Once because you're using SqlDataAdapter rather than SqlDataReader to retrieve the data. SqlDataReader pulls the data a row at a time.

Again because you're trying to put your entire output into a single text string. This works badly (a) because it takes a lot of RAM, and 
(b) because  `str = str+whatever` has to copy the string, erase the old one, and store the new one.  So

```
 string str = null;
 foreach (item in someLargeCollection) str = str + item;
```

runs in O(n-squared) time. When n (the size of the collection) is bigger than a few hundred items, that looks like a timeout.

So, quick fix:

```
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
         foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
         {
             csv += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
         }
         csv += "\r\n";
         Response.Write(csv);
         csv = null;
     }
```

This writes out each line, keeping csv from getting too big, and solves the second problem.

StringBuilder fix ... the right way to build strings:

```
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
         StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
         foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
         {
             csv.Append(row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',');
         }
         csv.AppendLine();
         Response.Write(csv.ToString());
     }
```

StringBuilder defeats the O(n-squared) problem when creating text strings.

Finally, you should look up the SqlDataReader class.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand why it was taking so long now. Brilliant explanation, and the code worked!! :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, string concatenation is very slow, because strings in C# are immutable. I suggest you use the StringBuilder class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to construct your string.